The geometry $\text{ Proj } \mathbb{C}[t][x_0,...,x_n] $.
Sorry this quite a vague question partly because I want to understand the geometry of this space and types of subschemes it contains.
I would like to understand the geometry of $\text{ Proj } \mathbb{C}[t][x_0,...,x_n] $ and it's relationship top $\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{A}^1$ .
Sorry about the vagueness of such question. Naively, I believe these two are the same space but most likely wrong

What do you mean by $\operatorname{Proj}\mathbb C[t][x_1,\dots,x_n]$? What is the grading on this ring?

Degree t is 0 and $x_i's$ 1

Gotcha, I am writing an answer now :)

$\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}$
$\C[t][x_0,\dots, x_n]$ is the ring $\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]$, with grading $\deg t=0$, $\deg x_i=1$, and we will assume that $\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]$ carries this grading going forward. We set $X=\Proj\C[t][x_0,\dots, x_n]$, and then as you guessed, this is naturally isomorphic to the fibre product $\mathbb P^n_{\C}\times_{\C} \mathbb A^1_{\C}$. Indeed, there is an open cover of $X$ by $\Spec (\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]_{x_i})_0$, and an open cover of the fibre product by $\Spec (\C[x_0,\dots, x_n]_{x_i})_0\otimes_{\C} \C[t]$. These affine schemes are obviously isomorphic, and I'll leave it to you to check that the these isomorphisms agree on the overlaps (this gluing should not be difficult).
Now, via this isomorphism it follows that the closed subschemes of $X$ are precisely the closed subschemes of the fibre product $\mathbb P^n_{\C}\times_{\C} \mathbb A^1_{\C}$. In particular, we have that if $Z\subset \mathbb P^n_{\C}$ and $Y\subset \mathbb A^1_{\C}$ are closed subschemes then there is an induced morphism $Z\times_{\C} Y\rightarrow \mathbb P^n_{\C}\times_{\C} \mathbb A^1_{\C}$ which is a closed embedding, so $Z\times_{\C}Y$ is a closed subscheme. This holds in generality, for any fibre product.
The converse, however, does not hold. Since $X$ is quasicompact, we can identify all closed subschemes of $X$ with the vanishing locus of homogenous ideals of $\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]$. If the converse were true, then we could take a homogenous ideal $I$ of $\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]$ and obtain an isomorphism:
$$\C[t,x_0,\dots, x_n]/I\cong\C[t]/I_t\otimes_\C \C[x_0,\dots, x_n]/I_x$$
where $I_x$ is homogenous, and the isomorphism is given on simple tensors by $[f]\otimes [g]\mapsto [fg]$.
Take $\C[t,x,y]$, and the ideal $I=\langle txy\rangle$. Then $\C[t,x,y]/I$ is not an integral domain, so if $I_t$ and $I_x$ exist, then one of $\C[t]/I_t$ or $\C[x,y]/I_x$ must not be an integral domain. If the first is not an integral domain, then we that there exist polynomials $f,g$ solely in $t$ such that $[f]\cdot [g]=0\in \C[t]/I_t$. However, this would imply that $fg\in \C[t,x,y]$ lie in $I$, which is certainly false as they contain no $x$ or $y$ terms. The same argument applies to $\C[x,y]$, hence not every closed subscheme is of this form.
Edit: why the downvote? Have I said something incorrect?

Thanks this really helpful to me! Excellent description

I guess based on your contruction this can be generalised to $\mathbb{P}^n \times_\mathbb{K} \mathbb{K}$ for any field \mathbb{K} , but not for aribitrary graded rings, i.e when degree $x_i \neq x_j$. @Chris

@benhuni I’m not sure what you mean. Nothing in this really depends on the base ring
